# NSTimer in background, then resuming (Swift)

Tags: swift, nstimer

Let's say I have a variable named number

```
var number: Int = 100
```

If I have an NSTimer that takes one of the number variable every second, and the user closes the app for... 20 seconds, when the user comes back onto the app, how am I able to get the new number variable after it has been running in the background for 20 seconds?

Comment: Just a quick idea but maybe you can use the methods in your app delegate to record the time when the app enters the background and foreground then update your variable accordingly.

Comment: In fact @thefredelement gave an answer to your question, is better to use the app delegates methods to know when your app enter in background and wakes up and calculate the time passed between two time, because in your case you can not put a NSTimer running in background for more than 180s ~

Answer (score 1):

Just base it on the absolute time, not on a local recounting. If you need the ticks (e.g. to update an on-screen counter) then:

```
var timer: NSTimer?
var timerStartTime: NSTimeInterval = 0.0

func startTimer() {
    timer = NSTimer(... to call myself every second ...)
    timerStartTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
}

func timerCallback(timer: NSTimer!) {
    let timeSinceTimerBegan = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() - timerStartTime

    print("It has now been \(timeSinceTimerBegan) seconds since timing began; 
                                        counter should be at \(100 - timeSinceTimerBegan)")
}
```